# How to pass an argument with space from bash script to bash script?

Tags: bash, list, for-loop, argument-passing, git-bash

I have a script the manipulates data, creates arguments and sends them to a second script. One of the arguments contains a space.

script1.sh:

```
args=()
args+=("A")
args+=("1 2")
args+=("B")
. script2.sh ${args[@]}
```

script2.sh:

```
for f in "$@"
do
  echo f=$f
done
```

I'd like to get `"1 2"` as single argument, but receive them separately:

```
f=A
f=1
f=2
f=B
```

I tried also converting the input in script2 to list `in=($@)` and iterating over it using `for f in ${in[@]}` but got the same result.

So, the problem might be in one of the following: building the list of arguments ; passing the built list ; parsing the input ; or iterating over the input.

**How to pass an argument with space from bash script to bash script?** Thanks.

* I'm using git-bash on Windows.

Comment: A combination of `"${args[@]}"` with `for f in "$@"` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Just for the record `for f; do` is the same as `for f in "$@"; do`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add quotes when passing the array as an argument:

```
args=()
args+=("A")
args+=("1 2")
args+=("B")
. script2.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: On the receiving side, use quotes, too: `in=("$@")`

Comment: A combination of `"${args[@]}"` with `for f in "$@"` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka I was going to suggest the `for f in "$@"` but in your example it was already quoted so I was puzzled.