# How to pass array to bash shell script?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

How do I pass an array as a variable from a first bash shell script to a second script.

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
sh second.sh "$AR" # foo
sh second.sh "${AR[@]}" # foo
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=$1
echo ${ARR[@]}
```

In both cases, the result is `foo`. But the result I want is `foo bar baz bat`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019389/passing-an-array-from-one-bash-script-to-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
sh second.sh "${AR[@]}"
```

which split the array elements in different arguments, i.e

```
sh second.sh "${A[0]}" "${A[1]}" "${A[2]}" ...
```

and in `second.sh` use

```
ARR=("$@")
```

to collect the command line arguments into an array.

Comment: By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `ARR=$1` in `second.sh` with `ARR=("$@")`.
`$1` assumes a single variable but you need to serialize all array items.

Comment: @jofel http://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/3023116

Comment: Of course I did. Otherwise I wouldn't post it here